# How to convert a FBX made by blender 2.8 in to a `g3db/g3dj` file?

Tags: libgdx

I've tried to convert a simple cube with libGDX  [FBX-Converter](https://github.com/libgdx/fbx-conv) but the cube is't displaying in my game app.

The FBX file is created by blender 2.8

This is the g3dj file

```
{
    "version": [  0,   1], 
    "id": "", 
    "meshes": [
        {
            "attributes": ["POSITION", "NORMAL", "TEXCOORD0"], 
            "vertices": [
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.750000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.750000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.750000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.750000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.125000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.125000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.875000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.875000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000
            ], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "id": "Cube_part1", 
                    "type": "TRIANGLES", 
                    "indices": [
                          0,   1,   2,   1,   0,   3,   4,   5,   6,   5,   4,   7, 
                          8,   9,  10,   9,   8,  11,  12,  13,  14,  13,  12,  15, 
                         16,  17,  18,  16,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  22,  21,  23
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "materials": [
        {
            "id": "green", 
            "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
            "diffuse": [ 0.018407,  0.800000,  0.000000], 
            "emissive": [ 0.018407,  0.800000,  0.000000], 
            "opacity":  0.000000, 
            "specular": [ 0.018407,  0.800000,  0.000000], 
            "shininess":  25.000000
        }
    ], 
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "Cube", 
            "rotation": [-0.707107,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107], 
            "scale": [ 10.000000,  10.000000,  10.000000], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "meshpartid": "Cube_part1", 
                    "materialid": "green", 
                    "uvMapping": [[]]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "animations": []
}
```

This file doesn't display on my game app. 
On the other hand, if I make an FBX file with blender 2.76 and then convert it to g3dj file it displays successfully.

Any ideas on how to convert an FBX made by blender 2.8 into a `g3db/g3dj` file?

**UPDATE:**

The only difference between the working one vs the not working one is attribute `TEXCOORD0`

heres 2 `g3dj` files, the one made with blender 2.76, and the one made with blender 2.8

**The g3dj file which converted an FBX file made with blender 2.76(the one that works):**

```
{
    "version": [  0,   1], 
    "id": "", 
    "meshes": [
        {
            "attributes": ["POSITION", "NORMAL"], 
            "vertices": [
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000
            ], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "id": "Cube.002_part1", 
                    "type": "TRIANGLES", 
                    "indices": [
                          0,   1,   2,   2,   1,   3,   4,   5,   6,   6,   5,   7, 
                          8,   9,  10,  10,   9,  11,  12,  13,  14,  14,  13,  15, 
                         16,  17,  18,  17,  19,  18,  20,  21,  22,  21,  20,  23
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "materials": [
        {
            "id": "Material.005", 
            "ambient": [ 0.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000], 
            "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "emissive": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "opacity":  1.000000, 
            "specular": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000], 
            "shininess":  9.607843
        }
    ], 
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "Cube", 
            "rotation": [-0.707107, -0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107], 
            "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  0.158538], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "meshpartid": "Cube.002_part1", 
                    "materialid": "Material.005"
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "animations": []
}
```

**And heres the g3dj file which converted an FBX file made with blender 2.8(the one that DO NOT work):**

```
{
    "version": [  0,   1], 
    "id": "", 
    "meshes": [
        {
            "attributes": ["POSITION", "NORMAL", "TEXCOORD0"], 
            "vertices": [
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.750000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  1.000000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.750000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.750000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.750000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.375000,  0.000000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.375000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.125000,  0.250000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.125000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000, -1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000, -1.000000,  0.375000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.875000,  0.500000, 
                -1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.875000,  0.250000, 
                 1.000000,  1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.625000,  0.500000, 
                 1.000000, -1.000000,  1.000000,  0.000000,  0.000000,  1.000000,  0.625000,  0.250000
            ], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "id": "Cube.001_part1", 
                    "type": "TRIANGLES", 
                    "indices": [
                          0,   1,   2,   1,   0,   3,   4,   5,   6,   5,   4,   7, 
                          8,   9,  10,   9,   8,  11,  12,  13,  14,  13,  12,  15, 
                         16,  17,  18,  16,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  22,  21,  23
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "materials": [
        {
            "id": "Material.002", 
            "ambient": [ 0.050876,  0.050876,  0.050876], 
            "diffuse": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "emissive": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "opacity":  0.000000, 
            "specular": [ 0.800000,  0.800000,  0.800000], 
            "shininess":  25.000000
        }
    ], 
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "Cube", 
            "rotation": [-0.707107, -0.000000,  0.000000,  0.707107], 
            "scale": [ 1.000000,  1.000000,  0.081716], 
            "parts": [
                {
                    "meshpartid": "Cube.001_part1", 
                    "materialid": "Material.002", 
                    "uvMapping": [[]]
                }
            ]
        }
    ], 
    "animations": []
}
```

So is there a way to omit this attribute in blender 2.8? or even better make libgdx take into account this attribute?

Comment: What are you using to convert to g3dj?  It sounds like Blender > Export to FBX > fbx-conv (what version, what command?) > copy to your libgdx project.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this is a `materials` problem.

For some reason FBX converter is writing `opacity` to `0.000000` why? I don't know. But for now, a workaround is to change it to `1.000000` in the `g3dj` file under `materials` block

Also, the material color is taken from the `Viewport Display` section `Color` and not from the `Surface` `Color` section of blender.

Note that this is not a `blender 2.8` problem as I believed at first if you change the render engine to cycles in `blender 2.76` FBX converter will write the material with opacity `0.00000` too

This of course is only valid if your using `g3dj` file, if someone has a better solution please do answer, at this point any solution is better than this.